# Replace the characters in every line of a file, if it match a condition - Unix

Tags: unix, replace, sed, match, conditional-statements

I have a file "dummy" in which:
If 15 character of the file matches with "R" and 28 character of the file matches with "D"
then 53-56 characters should be replaced with 0.

I have tried using the below script, but it's not working.

```
for i in `cat dummy`
do
    if [[ `echo $i | cut -c15` = "R" ]] && [[ `echo $i | cut -c28` = "D" ]]
then
   sed -e 's/./0/53' -e 's/./0/54' -e 's/./0/55' -e 's/./0/56'
fi
done
```

Input File: dummy

```
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130800031300SL07Y051
05196220141228R201412241308A201412220350SA0731SU1950LAX C00020202020
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130823455300SL07Y051
05196220141228N201412241308A201412240007TU0548WE1107MEL C00000000015
07054820141228N201412220850D201412180300TH1400MO085000040300UL180001
```

Output should be:

```
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130800001300SL07Y051
05196220141228R201412241308A201412220350SA0731SU1950LAX C00020202020
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130800005300SL07Y051
05196220141228N201412241308A201412240007TU0548WE1107MEL C00000000015
07054820141228N201412220850D201412180300TH1400MO085000040300UL180001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to loop through the file with a bash loop. `sed` alone can handle it:

```
$ sed -r '/^.{14}R.{12}D/s/(.{52}).{4}/\10000/' file
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130800001300SL07Y051
05196220141228R201412241308A201412220350SA0731SU1950LAX C00020202020
05196220141228R201412241308D201412200055SA1155WE130800005300SL07Y051
05196220141228N201412241308A201412240007TU0548WE1107MEL C00000000015
07054820141228N201412220850D201412180300TH1400MO085000040300UL180001
```

This uses the expression `sed '/pattern/s/X/Y/' file`: in lines matching `pattern`, replace `X` with `Y`.

In this case,

- `/^.{14}R.{12}D/` line starts with any 14 characters followed by `R`, then any 12 characters followed by `D`.
- `(.{52}).{4}` look for any 52 characters followed by any 4 characters and replace them with...
- `\10000` the first block followed by `0000`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ll try this command and let u know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will try with the command and let you know the result shortly.

Comment: may i propose `sed -r '/^\(.{14}R\).{12}D/ s//\10000/' file` using the last pattern (`//`) in following `s`action

Comment: @NeronLeVelu thanks but note the block to be printed back is based on the 52 first characters, which is not the same as the 14 in the pattern.

Comment: oops you are right, write without correctly read the request and reply, sorry

Comment: @NeronLeVelu no problem! i always learn a lot from your `sed` guru skills : )